# change input style of upload

Tags: file-upload, bootstrap-4

i am trying to design a upload form which looks like this
[image]

this is what i have so far but i can not make it the way i want to

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLangHTML">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLangHTML" data-browse="Upload">Upload Your CV here</label>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle of what i have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/6sr9wfxn/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the font around to get that one but I think this should get you going in the right direction

```css
  .custom-file-label[data-browse]::after {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: orange;
      color: white;
      width: 8em;
  }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h3>
Careers
</h3>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLangHTML">
  <label class="custom-file-label text-center" for="customFileLangHTML" data-browse="Upload">Upload Your CV here</label>
</div>
```